# How to use VueJS with Zurb Panini?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vuejs2

Both VueJS and Zurb Panini use {{ variable }} as templates. How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Overcome what problem? Don't use them together?

Comment: Well. I am using them together. How do I differentiate panini partials from VueJS elements?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/Vlasterx/5310ed6cb8417d331c9f74808a345700

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I hadn't done a lot of research before posting my question.

You can change the delimiters of VueJS:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: data,
    delimiters: ["<%","%>"]
});
```

This will change `{{ variable }}` to `<% variable %>` and you should be good to go!

**Restriction: You should use the full build and not the runtime-only build.**

Links:

- [VueJS Build Terms](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Terms)
- [VueJS Instance Options](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters)